# Finding segments from a youtube video

Tags: youtube, segment

Is there an efficient way or a program to get all the segments from a youtube video?

I was thinking about using *youtube-dl* to download the manifest file but from what I have read it has no exact data on the segments.

I also tried google-ing it but I constantly come across how to play certain segments or insert/delete, which is not my interest. I want at a certain point to have a list of all the segments with start and end time.

Comment: Can you specify in your question which segment you want find? Can you add an example?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave If my understanding of the problem is correct, a video should be downloaded in segments. So I want to create a list of all of them

Comment: CroatiaHR, now I understand you. Thanks for clarify. Unfortunately I can't help you because I don't know, honestly  - *(I was think about the YouTube Data API)*, but you cannot use it because the YouTube Data API doesn't provide such details - as far as I know. Good luck.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no it doesn't.. I was hoping that maybe here I would get some good ideas, but....

Comment: you might get help, but, you have to provide in your question what have you tried so far. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Questions without showing any code tend to be ignored by the community. If you show some effort in your question *(and by following the steps provided in the link I share with you)* the community of Stack Overflow will give you more help. Good luck.